# Moment generating function if the PDF is $f_z= Cz^{k-1}(1-\frac{z}{d})^bF(-a+k+1,b;b+1;1-\frac{z}{d})$

Tags: probability, distributions, integral, hypergeometric-distribution, moment-generating-function

Let $z$  a random variable with PDF : $f_z= Cz^{k-1}(1-\frac{z}{d})^bF(-a+k+1,b;b+1;1-\frac{z}{d})$, where $0\leq z \leq d$, $F$ is the Hypergeometric function, $k$ is a positive integer, $-a+k+1 >0$, $C$ is a constant and $a ,b$ are 2 real positive numbers.

Please I need to compute a closed form of the Moment generating function of $z$.

Answer (score 1):

Using [well-known relationships](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html), simplify

$$(1-z)^b z^{k-1} \, _2F_1(b,-a+k+1;b+1;1-z) = b z^{k-1} B_{1-z}(b,a-k)$$

where $B$ is the incomplete Beta function

$$B_{1-z}(b,a-k) = \int_0^{1-z} t^{b-1} (1-t)^{a-k-1}dt.$$

To find the moments, switch the order of integration in computing

$$\nu_j = \int_0^1 z^j b z^{k-1} B_{1-z}(b,a-k) dz =\frac{\Gamma(b+1)}{(j+k) (a+j)_b}$$

where $(a+j)_b = (a+j)(a+j+1)\cdots(a+j+b-1)$.  Therefore the raw moment of order $j$ is

$$\mu_j =\nu_j / \nu_1 = \frac{k (a)_b}{(j+k) (a+j)_b}.$$

The moment generating function is

$$f(t; a, b, k) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\mu_j t^j}{j!} = \, _2F_2(a,k;a+b,k+1;t),$$

a [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: In my case $a-k$<0, but I think that the parameters of an Incomplete Beta Function should be positives. Another issue is that $a,b$ are non-integers positive numbers but in your calculation(double integral) you have used the formula $B(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!} $ which is available if $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: I'm sorry; I had thought you were taking $a$ and $b$ to be integral. The issue with factorials is readily addressed by using Gamma functions. The issue with $a-k\lt 0$ needs to be looked into, because then the original simplification is not correct. An initial transformation of the hypergeometric function using one of [Euler's transformations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) is needed, such as $\,_2F_1(b,-a+k+1,b+1,1-z)=z^{k-a}\,_2F_1(1,b+a-k,b+1,1-z)$, and then the same analysis can be applied. I haven't the time to carry this out for you now.

Comment: When you have some time, Could you please give me more details about using gamma function and how to complete the calculation..   note that $a+b-k>0$, $a-k<0$ and $b-k>0$. Thank you!